# Unrecognised selector sent to instance When changing UIButton background

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, tags, uibutton, instance

Hey I am writing a function that handles favorites within my app, as well as changing the image of the favorite button I want to change the image of a corresponding button in another UIScrollView `DoubleScrollLeft`.

The below code works **HOWEVER** I get the following eror when trying to favorite my first button with the tag '0' is there a reason for this? (the rest work).

**-[UIScrollView setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e3b0**

Also once the images do change it pushes the title of the button off to the right, do i need to reset the frame etc.. when i change the background for state?

```
-(void)favButtons:(id)sender {

int i = [sender tag];
NSString *fav = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

    if ([[Favinsults objectForKey:fav] isEqualToString:@"0"]){

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIButton* button = (UIButton *)[DoubleScrollLeft viewWithTag:i];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonD1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favButton0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIButton* button = (UIButton *)[DoubleScrollLeft viewWithTag:i];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonD0.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a mis-connection where a `UIScrollview` is connected to the `IBAction` method. Check your IB connections carefully.

Comment: But why does it only happen when the sender tag is 0?

Comment: The default tag value is 0. If the sender is not what you expect, that is another class, there is a connection issue.

Comment: But it all works fine if I offset all of the sender tags by 1.

Comment: Programming by coincidence is a bad idea. Take the time to understand every line of code written, that pays off in the end. There is no mystery, the computer does **exactly** what it is asked to do, the problem is we ask it to do the wrong thing to often.

Comment: Very well said, which exactly why I am trying to find out why it does this when my tag is 0!?

Comment: Suggestion, delete all your IBActions in Interface Builder and then recreate them one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your sender is somehow UIScrollview.

Change this line as,  This should avoid the warning message.

```
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[((UIButton *)sender) setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks but this dosen't work, I think the UIScroll view confusion is happening here > `UIButton* button = (UIButton *)[DoubleScrollLeft viewWithTag:i];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the sender to a UIButton before you can call any of the UIButton methods on it...

```
UIButton * newbutton = (UIButton*)sender;
[newbutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favButton1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

etc.

```
[UIScrollView setBackgroundImage:forState:]
```

means that your sender is interpreted to be of type UIScrollView (not UIButton), and there is no method `setBackgroundImage:forState:` defined in UIScrollView.

Comment: Please can you show how I would use this along with `[DoubleScrollLeft viewWithTag:i]` to change the background image of a button within my second UIScrollView